# jquery render partial just one time, for second time it not render again just shows previous one

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, view, partial-views, renderpartial

I've to append partial by jquery for my scenario I can't render partial using ajax as it needs controller's interaction and I'm restricted to not use controller.

So I'm doing this

```
$('#button_add').click(function(){

  $('#content_form_div').append("
    <%= j render(:partial=> 'pages/content/call_text_phone',
:locals => @locals.merge!(counter: cookies[:counter] + 1 ),
 :formats=>[:html]) %>");
   });
```

It first time render partial but second time it does not actually render partial.

Any idea to do this without using ajax.

Comment: Can you place the stuff into a hidden element and display and/or clone it on click? Seems to me this can't work because line breaks will mess up the JavaScript.

Comment: @Juhana I added line break for question purpose not in my code :)

Comment: Yes, but I assume the partial contains line breaks (and maybe quotes).

Comment: Nope  that was not the case @Juhana btw thanks for responses. I resolved it as I stated below my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time on my own solution, things got crazy as there is code messing up and more lines of code.

For nested forms I got this as solution for me as it also not requires controller's interaction.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

and one more thing, I added getRandomInt in jquery to create unique id which is neccessary to avoid duplication of timestamp for fields created instantly with no time difference.

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
 // I changed below line by adding getRandomInt method to assure unique id. 
  var new_id = new Date().getTime() + getRandomInt(1, 5000);
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(".all_fields").append(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rerender anything on the screen you need to reload it (or recreate it in javascript) to me it would seem that you embed static HTML and the script the does what it's told. It renders the static HTML.

Comment: As the  code above in question depicts that I'm rendering partial with new values each time so how could it be static page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that '@locals.merge!(counter: cookies[:counter] + 1 )' would be evaluated on the server and outputted as a literal value. Check the generated html in your browser and you'll be able to see if that's the case

Comment: yeah I also think so as that cookie value is not changing every time it renders partial, I found a good way to do this instead of this way