# Ruby on rails - paperclip not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm trying to make a create product page in rails. This includes adding multiple images. I have one model for products one for photos and for users. I'm using the paperclip gem for photo upload. But I have 2 problems.

1. My file input is ***not*** allowing me to select multiple images
2. When I view a product no pictures show because pictures ***are not being saved to database***

P.S. I use HAML and I dont have a photo controller.

**Products controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :destory]
    before_filter :correct_user, only: :destory

  def new 
@product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
    5.times { @product.photos.build }
  end

  def create

  @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])

  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    if @product.save
        render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
        render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end

def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

**create product page**

```
= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  - if @product.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @product.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = fields_for :photos do |f_i|
      =f_i.file_field :image 

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

**product model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :condition, :ship_method, :ship_price, :quantity, :photo
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  belongs_to :user
```

**photo model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id

  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "300x300>",
      :large => "600x600>"
        }
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name

  attr_accessor :password
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos,:through=>:products
```

**show product page**

```
  %b seller
  = @product.user.name
  %br 
  - @product.photos.each do |photo|
    = image_tag photo.image.url
```

Comment: what about your User model do you have the method: User has many :photos ,:through=>:products ?

Comment: no i dont i have has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

Comment: I had typos just fixed them!

Comment: havent looked extensively but have you tried something like, f.fields_for @photo do |fp|

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: @ajt yeah  idid it's right there in the first code block.....

Comment: Check out my update in the original post some things changed

Comment: @AlainGoldman you have not posted your user model here but as far as I can tell you can not build photos from current user because photos does not belong to the user model and your newly built product does not have an id yet. Look at my answer again, I fixed the photo, photos typo.

Comment: i don't understood so far why you are asking same question again... What about old one? you are wasting others time.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500711/rails-paperclip-multiple-photo-upload-not-saving

Comment: and third one is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807112/rails-paperclip-is-not-adding-my-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `Resque` for background job,if yes then u need to start it using `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'`.in rails usually `Resque` is used to handle background jobs which involves mailer and picture upload.OR an example below for product.html.erb having partial for photos upload for that product with paperclip configures with Amazon S3.

product.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'photos' %>
```

_photos.html.erb for atleast one image mandatory

```
       <% if @product.photos[0].nil? %>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-photos" >
                <img src="/assets/default/product-add-photos.png" alt="Add product photos"/>              
                 </a>   
        <% end %>
 <img src="<%= (@product.product_photos[0].nil? ? "" : @product.photos[0].image.url(:small)) %>" id="photos_1" class="product-photos-src <%=@product.photos[0].nil? ? 'dontdisplay' : ''%> "/>
```

Answer (score 3):

your User model not attached to photos so photos only are belongs to Product model so you need to change your User model to be

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :photos,:through=>:products


  end
```

then you can fetch User photos through

```
 @photos =current_user.photos
```

or you can build a photo easily

```
@photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])
```

also in your views  you need to do instead of 
      = f.file_field :photo, multiple: 'multiple'

use

```
= fields_for :photos do |f_i|
    =f_i.file_field :image
```

try it .

these is the simple way for has many through association

```
   class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :paragraphs, :through => :sections
  end

 class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :document
  has_many :paragraphs
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :section
 end
```

you can check these guide for more info

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
also you need to put

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

inside your Product model

for a complete tutorial about nested forms you can watch these screen cast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

its not free

you can watch these free screen cast if your not subscribed to railscasts.com

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Hmnn i did that change did bundle exec rake db:migrate then restarted the server but i still get the same error

Comment: in your product model you need to put has_many :photos instead of   has_attached_file :photo so it will work

Comment: undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass

Comment: add accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos to your Product model

Comment: also remove @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo]) as photos will be build as nested inside product form

Comment: i removed @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo]) and  added accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos to product model but i still get  undefined method 'photos' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

new product page

```
= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description

  = f.fields_for :photo do |fp|
    = fp.file_field :image
    = fp.check_box :_destroy
    = fp.label :_destroy, "Remove Image" 

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

products controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.photos.build
end

def create  
  @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
  # or
  # @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
  # @product.save
end
```

product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :photo
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :reject_if => lambda { |p| p[:image].nil? }, :allow_destroy => true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  validates :user_id,      presence: true
  validates :photo,        presence: true
end
```

photo model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  belongs_to :product
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
         content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
         size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

end
```

Comment: with that i get  NoMethodError in ProductsController#new

undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: see updated code and use '@product.build_photo' instead of '@product.photo.build'

Comment: @AlainGoldman the issue was a typo on my part I had '@product.photo.build' and it should have been '@product.photos.build'.

Comment: @SachinSingh Thanks for the edit but this is an has_many association not a has_one.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using nested form, you dont need to create each object separately. Creating product will create the nested photo.
2. `build` method only creates an object. It doesnt save the object to db. You should call `object.save` or use `create` method instead of `build` in your create action

Comment: i've used build to create a product without a photo

Comment: @AlainGoldman, The photo attributes are nested inside product attributes and params will look like this `:product => {:description => 'blah blah', :photo_attributes => {:image => "<File>"}}`. So when you create a product object, an associated photo is also created.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue here is that you want to attach multiple photo's on one model through paperclip.
Paperclip can only attach 1 file per model, so I suggest you do this:

```
1. create model Photo with paperclip migrations + has_attached_file
2. Product has_many :photos
3. (optional) make a function to return all image urls, otherwise just call the method in the view

   class Product 
     def get_pics
        photos.collect{|p| p.image.url}
     end
   end
```

Also a good thing, you can include meta data like alt texts and stuff in the photo model now!

```
<% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag photo.image.url, :alt => photo.alt_text %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same issue. I asked on stackoverflow and finally solved myself and rails cast help.

**First thing to change is:**
You have to follow this to implement nested attributes in model side and controller end:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Then follow the link below, check my answer to the question it includes rails cast links that you should follow for nested forms:

You will see rails cast 2nd link dynamically separate your each filed field as on its own it fails to separate each set of fields. But there is also lack of identity uniqueness algo accuracy in rails-cast. So I enhanced to make sure the uniqueness of certain set of fields to other.

[jquery render partial just one time, for second time it not render again just shows previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184102/jquery-render-partial-just-one-time-for-second-time-it-not-render-again-just-sh)